# Is there any solution to extract all data from collection?

Tags: anylogic

I want to know how to extract all data from the collection. I cannot see more than 10 data. Is there any solution to this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Write the values of the items within the collection into a csv/txt/xlsx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to view the data while the simulation is running the best option is to traceln the data to the console. From there you can copy it and analyze it as you want.

Based on your example you can have a button with the following code.

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion!
It works very well!

Comment: Thank you! remember to accept my answer and upvote it if you think it worthy ;-)